# Export right-to-left from RadGridView

Tags: excel, silverlight, export, right-to-left, radgridview

I have a Silverlight application which has a RadGridView that is right to left.
when I export the grid, the result is left to right table.
I want the exported table would be in right to left format
(for example in Excel the sheet would be in right to left direction)

*Edit not from OP to transfer clarification provided in comment*

This picture is from the export result:

[image: !ExportResult.]

and this one is when I change sheet direction manually:

[image: !ExportResultAfterSheetDirection.]

Comment: No, it's make no sense for Export

Comment: maybe, but I prefer to change Excel sheet direction to right-to-left dynamically, because when I do it manually, it shows columns correctly!

Comment: This picture is from the export result ![ExportResult](http://upload7.ir/images/43837988102483023595.jpg).
and this one is when i change sheet direction manually ![ExportResultAfterSheetDirection](http://upload7.ir/images/06167593874508605680.jpg).

Answer (score 3):

By adding some styling at the header part of your output in the export function, and for the Right-to-left alignment option it's inserted at the **`<WorksheetOptions>`** level of the declaration which called **`<x:DisplayRightToLeft/>`**.

Example if you're using C# in your project:

```
private string AddExcelStyling()
{

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'\n" +

    "xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel'\n" +

    "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>\n" +

    "<head>\n");

    sb.Append("<style>\n");

    sb.Append("@page");

    sb.Append("mso-page-orientation:landscape;}\n");

    sb.Append("</style>\n");

    sb.Append("<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>\n");

    sb.Append("<x:ExcelWorkbook>\n");

    sb.Append("<x:ExcelWorksheets>\n");

    sb.Append("<x:ExcelWorksheet>\n");

    sb.Append("<x:Name>Sheet Name</x:Name>\n");

    sb.Append("<x:WorksheetOptions>\n");

    sb.Append("<x:Print>\n");

    sb.Append("<x:HorizontalResolution>600</x:HorizontalResolution\n");

    sb.Append("<x:VerticalResolution>600</x:VerticalResolution\n");

    sb.Append("</x:Print>\n");

    sb.Append("<x:Selected/>\n");

    sb.Append("<x:DisplayRightToLeft/>\n");

    sb.Append("<x:DoNotDisplayGridlines/>\n");

    sb.Append("</x:WorksheetOptions>\n");

    sb.Append("</x:ExcelWorksheet>\n");

    sb.Append("</x:ExcelWorksheets>\n");

    sb.Append("</x:ExcelWorkbook>\n");

    sb.Append("</xml><![endif]-->\n");

    sb.Append("</head>\n");

    sb.Append("<body>\n");

    return sb.ToString();

}
```

See this link: http://forums.asp.net/p/1445619/3358464.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but because I use telerik RadGridView, I use its export function and I do not know how to set these style for it!

Answer (score 1):

I still have next to no idea of what is required, but here are some possibilities:

Starting with this:

[image: SO18980638 first example]

sort ABC columns: Row / Sort by Row 1; Sort On Values; Order Largest to Smallest to get:

[image: SO18980638 second example]

then click on Right-to-Left icon to get:

[image: SO18980638 third example]

and sort again (same selection) to get this:

[image: SO18980638 fourth example]

Stop when desired result is achieved.
Delete Row 1.
For code version click on Record Macro and repeat as many of above steps as required.
Stop recording.

Comment: Can I use Excel Macros from my application when I export the Grid?